# Numpy: Comparison within Multidimensional array values

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, indexing, slice

I have a 2D array in the following form:

```
[[X1, X2, ..., XN]
[Y1, Y2, ..., YN]]
```

For each `Xi` greater than `lower_limit_X` and less than `upper_limit_X`, I would like to get **the number of** `Yi`'s that are greater than `lower_limit_Y` and less than `upper_limit_Y`.

I hope there is an efficient way of doing this in Numpy apart from indexing one by one.

EDIT:
So I have a 2xN array. The first row has ordered values of N X's and second row has ordered values of N Y's. What I would like to get is:

1. get a the `lowest_index` and `highest_index` index of X, that have a value that is greater than `lower_limit_X` and less than `upper_limit_X`
2. then slice the Y array (just one array) in the index range [`lowest_index`, `highest_index`]
3. count the number of elements in my slice, having Yi`'s that are greater than`lower_limit_Y`and less than`upper_limit_Y`.

Comment: When you say "For each Xi", do you mean there are multiple rows of `Y`, or do you mean "for each unique value of Xi"?

Comment: Not sure to undersand... Is there an Yi array for each Xi ? EDIT: okay, same kind of question than NPE actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways you could do this, the more strait forward way is probably,

```
mask = ((lower_x_limit < array[0]) & (array[0] < upper_x_limit) &
        (lower_y_limit < array[1]) & (array[1] < upper_y_limit))
count = sum(mask)
```

If your array is very large and both x and y are sorted you could use `searchsorted` instead,

```
start = array[0].searchsorted(lower_x_limit, 'right')
end = array[0].searchsorted(upper_x_limit, 'left')
temp = array[1, start:end]
start = temp.searchsorted(lower_y_limit, 'right')
end = temp.searchsorted(upper_y_limit, 'left')
count = end - start
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [numpy.logical_and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html).

```
      numpy.logical_and(array1 > lower_x_limt, array1 < upper_x_limit)
```

this will do elementwise comparison and return a boolean list at indices which have your values.